# can WTForms check two password is or not same when someone register 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, passwords

[WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) is a forms validation and rendering library for python web development

and  i write this code to check two password is or not same :

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, validators

class SignUpForm(Form):
    username     = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Length(min=6, max=120), validators.Email()])
    password1 = PasswordField('Password1')
    password2 = PasswordField('Password2')

    def sameP(self):
        return self.password1 ==self.password2
```

but , i want to know : can WTForms do this themself .

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `wtforms.validators.EqualTo`.

It took less than a minute to find this in [TFM](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/validators.html), having never used this library before.

Comment: Is it just me, or is zjm getting worse all the time?